# can I use the MbUnit gui with Moles tests?

Tags: mbunit, gallio, pex, pex-and-moles, moles

I'd like to set up our unit tests to use Moles -- mostly so we don't write a lot of interfaces in places that don't call for interfaces. Ok, that part is debatable but it is a concern on our team.

To that end, we're investigating Moles. Moles is nifty. Pex is nifty. The issue is that if we build a unit test that uses Moles, suddenly we **can't run it in Gallio Icarus** (MbUnit gui). Is there a way to pull this off and get Icarus to understand that Moles is part of the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://geekswithblogs.net/thomasweller/archive/2010/04/28/mocking-the-unmockable-using-microsoft-moles-with-gallio.aspx

Comment: Right, I'd read that. It basically says "No". But it seemed old enough that maybe the info had changed. Hoping that Peli will see this post and have a comment.

Comment: I had a look at writing a Gallio extension, but it's a bit tricky due to the command line args for Moles. It expects _exactly_ one test assembly, no more, no less, when you start the process. It could be done, but it would be a bit hacky :(